# Is shared ground necessary?

Tags: uart, ground, communication

I ask this mainly for curiosity and am not trying to make shortcuts for real projects.

I have a couple of devices (mcu development boards) that connect to each other using various communication busses. One of which is UART.

For normal situations, you need a common ground as reference as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138706/does-ardunino-serial-need-a-common-ground

However, all my devices in my test setup get power from usb from the same computer. Accidentally, I disconnected one of the ground wires between two devices and everything remained working.

Is this just 'luck' or is it because the voltage source for all devices is the same?

Comment: There is still a ground path through the  other devices because all grounds meet at the PC

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but there are 5V to 3.3V converters as well, so I don't know how much that holds up.

Comment: 5 volt to 3.3 volt regulators normally use a common input/output ground connection.

Comment: *Accidentally, I disconnected one of the ground wires between two devices and everything remained working.* That's possible, the ground connection could be made elsewhere (a path you didn't think of). If the ground connection is **really** open then things can still work. If one of the signals is grounded (output = 0 Volt)  then through ESD protection diodes (present on nearly every IC's input) that output can pull the other ground close enough to ground level. Related video where supply is not connected but things still work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need a shared ground. The reason it works is because everything connected to your PC and share supply grounds. But it also means that the supply ground will be the reference to all your signals, which isn't ideal.

Ideally all communication lines include a signal ground, which is tied to the main ground of each PCB through appropriate PCB layout. That way you don't have to worry about the quality of the supply ground, where there could be ground currents messing up potentials, EMI etc.

Comment: That distinction isn't as great as you make it out to be.  You will get power currents flowing through your signal ground, or if its impedance is comparatively high enough that they mostly do not, then you will get the power driven differences appearing across it just as if it were not there...

Comment: Yes, connecting two board to same PC via USB will connect their grounds at the PC if they are not isolated. But as ground wires of each USB device can have different resistance and different current through them, so there can be a voltage difference between board grounds. Connecting an additional ground wire between boards will equalize the potential but can create a ground loop, which can cause return current of one board going via other board. But for data comms it is better to have direct ground return for data currents so they do not go via the USB wires and radiate.